# Count where one column in one row is equal to another column in another row

Tags: sql, sas

so I have a (simplified) table below.

| shift_id | employee_Nbr | begin_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 12 | 1/7/21 | 1/9/21 |
| 002 | 12 | 1/9/21 | 1/14/21 |
| 003 | 15 | 1/10/21 | 1/13/21 |
| 004 | 12 | 1/24/21 | 1/24/21 |
| 005 | 15 | 1/13/21 | 1/14/21 |

I am trying to count the number of times **the same employee** has an `end_dt` of one row equal to the `begin_dt` of another row. In this example the count would be two since rows (1&2) and rows (3&5) meet this criteria. Note that row 4 has a `begin_dt` equal to its own `end_dt` that that doesnt mean anything to me in this situation. I would also like to have this data in a table to be able to look back on rather than a simple count. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a unique key/identifier for these records? Otherwise the 4th line would cause most logic to trip as well since your condition is true in that same record. In other words, you have a second condition that isn't stated: "And the end_dt and begin_dt aren't from the same record" which is more difficult to solve without a unique key.

Comment: sorry I left that out! included now @Jnevill

Comment: Should have asked in my last comment. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: another thing I shouldve included, my bad there. SAS EG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also doable using a hash table; that might be the best option.  It's very fast, doesn't require a sort, and should avoid some of the issues you might have with a data step merge related to duplicate rows.

```
data have;
input shift_id $    employee_nbr $  begin_dt :mmddyy8. end_dt :mmddyy8.;
format begin_dt end_dt date9.;
datalines;
001 12  1/7/21  1/9/21
002 12  1/9/21  1/14/21
003 15  1/10/21 1/13/21
004 12  1/24/21 1/24/21
005 15  1/13/21 1/14/21
;
run;


data want;
  set have;
  
  ** Load up a hash table;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash h_enddt(dataset:'have');
    h_enddt.defineKey('employee_nbr','end_dt');  *these are the "unique key" to qualify a record as matching;
    h_enddt.defineData('employee_nbr');          *this is what to "output" when a match is found (basically, nothing here);
    h_enddt.defineDone();
  end;
  
  ** rc is the return code - 0 is "found", nonzero is "not found";
  ** this does a search in the hash table, using employee_nbr and begin_dt values as the match keys;
  ** So, "current record" begin_dt is compared to "hash table" end_dt, and it returns 0 if it is found;
  rc = h_enddt.find(key:employee_nbr,key:begin_dt);
  
  ** Now, output rows if "current record" begin_dt is not equal to "current record" end_dt, and a match is found (rc=0);
  if begin_dt ne end_dt and rc eq 0 then output;
run;
```

Note the 1/24 date is handled by just rejecting rows where begin_dt = end_dt; if your rule for rejecting that is different, you might have to have something else added (like a row number variable) to make sure you're not getting a self-match.

Comment: so this definitely runs WAY faster but does the opposite (only keeps that 1/24 condition and not the rest). I honestly have no idea what is going on here (most of my experience is SQL) so not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @MichaelAncel It keeps the right 2 records for me! Maybe you switched eq and ne? I'll comment things up a bit so it makes more sense hopefully.

Comment: I added some comments!

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to show both sides of the records? I.E instead of grabbing 2 records in this example grab all 4 records? This way allows me to find the count easily but makes it slightly more difficult to do things afterwards with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can self join this table and exclude on your unique key:

```
select t.*
    , t2.*
    , count(case when t2.shift_id is not null then 1 end) over ()
from t
left join t t2
    on (
        t.begin_dt = t2.end_dt
        or t.end_dt = t2.begin_dt
        )
    and t.employee_Nbr = t2.employee_Nbr
    and t.shift_id <> t2.shift_id
```

This can give you all of the data with matches as well as a count of matched rows, but I'm not entirely sure I understood what you are counting, so feel free to let me know if you are trying to count something specific.

Comment: I am correct in replacing "from t" with "from rotn as t" and "left join t t2" with "left join rotn as t2" if the name of my table is rotn correct? It is running incredibly slowly and wanted to make sure that is the right interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want using a SAS datastep.
If you are using SAS viya you can avoid using the two Proc sorts by running the Data  step on CAS.

It is basically joining the table with ifself but excluding the cases where the shift_id is the same.

As for the actual counting, you can then just check how many observations the table has, or run a proc freq if you want to count by employee. Didn't include it because I did't know. Let me know

```
data have;
infile datalines dlm='09'x;
input shift_id $    employee_Nbr $  begin_dt    $ end_dt $;
datalines;
001 12  1/7/21  1/9/21
002 12  1/9/21  1/14/21
003 15  1/10/21 1/13/21
004 12  1/24/21 1/24/21
005 15  1/13/21 1/14/21
;
run;

proc sort data=have (rename=(begin_dt=matchdate)) out=have1;
by employee_nbr matchdate;
run;

proc sort data=have (rename=(end_dt=matchdate)) out=have2;
by employee_nbr matchdate;
run;

data want;
    merge have1 (in=s1) have2 (in=s2 rename=(shift_id=shift_id2));
    by employee_nbr matchdate;
    if s1 and s2 and shift_id ne shift_id2; *keep if dates match and it is not the same shift;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select count(*)
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.employee_Nbr = t.employee_Nbr  and 
        t2.end_dt = t.begin_dt
where t.end_dt <> t.begin_dt and
      t2.end_dt <> t2.begin_dt;
```